# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/internal/inject/Binder when started Tomcat Server

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey, glassfish

I am building REST API in Java with Jersey and Maven. I used Tomcat 9 as my server. Everything works fine until I tried to install **RestAssured,** **Hamcrest,** and **JUnit** today. Suddenly all of my endpoints threw out 500 Internal server errors. The root cause of the 500 error is `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/internal/inject/Binder.`

What I have done this 2 hours:

- I have tried to find this class: `org/glassfish/jersey/internal/inject/Binder` on google, but no avail.
- I have tried to uninstall **RestAssured**, **Hamcrest**, and **JUnit** but it didn't help.

This problem makes me frustrated. Any idea why this errors happened? Thanks in advance!

Here is the excerpt of the server log:

> **SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet Jersey Web Application java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Binder**
>       at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1275)
>       at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1109)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:178)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:370)
>       at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:779)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:475)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:498)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:796)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1368)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Below is my `pom.xml` file: (with RestAssured, Hamcrest, and JUnit)

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
        <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Below is my web.xml file:

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.accelbyte.vincent.emailist.resources</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Below is my project structure:

[Email list project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s95Al.png)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Very likely there is a version mismatch between core `Jersey` and one of the `Jersey` extension libraries that imports that `Binder` class. Make sure all Jersey-related modules have explicit versions (and they match each other). Or even better, fix your versions by importing the jersey-bom. E.g.:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.26-b03</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

After which your main `<dependencies>` section may omit the versions.

Comment: Thank you. But I solved it by restarting the Eclipse.

Comment: If you have any extra jersey modules, make sure they don't have explicit versions in the pom. Let them fallback on the version in dependency management.

Comment: If I am getting it right, then jersey-bom contains all reset related jars. Right?

Answer (score 4):

I have faced the same issue with using different versions. Make sure your Jersey-bean-validation and Jersey-container-servlet **versions** are the same.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.22</version>
</dependency>
<!-- bean validation -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
    <version>2.22</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Same problem with you. keeping the `jersey-bean-validation` and `jersey-container-servlet` the same version works well.